# Centralize <thead> in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

How can I centralize a thead text in HTML tables?

I'm trying this:

```
...
<thead rowspan="3" align="center">
   <th> Table </th>
</thead>
...
```

Comment: Use `text-align:center` in css, add `align=center` to th tag, or use `style='text-align:center'` to th tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th style="text-align: center"> Table </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving th width of 100% with text-aling:center as style property